# Как перенести сайт с html на php так чтобы гугл сохранил позицию страниц в поиске

Tags: php, html, seo, sitemap, google-search

Хотел бы добавлять статьи через phpMyAdmin или даже Wordpres, но я опасаюсь ситуации что гугл не поймет что exemple.com/article/page.html стал exemple.com/pages/page.php?**id=7**

Поймет ли гугл что произошло ясли я просто изменю sitemap?

Comment: с поомщью htaccess вы с успехом можете перенаправлять запросы вида `article/page7.html`  в `page/page.php?id=7`. так что внешние ссылки на сайте не изменятся.

Comment: Спасибо способ с htaccess мне подходит. Только не понятно будет ли гугл  индексировать php файл вместо html и кому из них будет + в позиции в поиске.